# Generate dynamic schedule for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design

I need to implement scheduling task for my application. Let's say application display popup questions fetching the schedule data from database.

Heres the database table structure -[image]

Now i want to display question's to logged in user from QuestionSchedule table.
Heres the scenario - Question1 should displays X repeatable_times after each X repeat_after_days.
Example - Question1 should displays 3 repeatable_times after each 2 repeat_after_days.

Note - UserQuestionAnswer should not display duplicate entry with calculate the UserQuestionAnswer and QuestionSchedule table.

Details data -
Question (id-1, title- What is your level of confidence for todays task ?)
QuestionSchedule(id-1,question_id-1,repeatable_times-3,repeat_after_days-2)
UserQuestionAnswer(id-1,question_id-1,user_id-1,answer_at-(2018-08-27))

Now i want to generate schedule on fly -

2018-08-25 -> Schedule is created

2018-08-26 -> Should not display

2018-08-27 -> Should display and add answer to UserQuestionAnswer table not twice

2018-08-28 -> Should not display

2018-08-29 -> Should display and add answer to UserQuestionAnswer table not twice

2018-08-30 -> Should not display

2018-08-31 -> Should display and add answer to UserQuestionAnswer table not twice

Comment: Scenario and example are different. Can you please clarify on the note part too?

Comment: @Arihant I updated the question description. Please help